# Length of array in Typescript - access members

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I have a declared type

```
type Vehiculo={
  [key: string]: string;
};

let allCars:Vehiculo = {Ford: "Ka", GM:"Sonic", Audi:"A4"};
```

How can I get the length of this array?

Definitely, allCars.length is not right

Comment: That's not an array, it's a plain object.  If you want the number of entries you can do  `Object.keys(allCars).length`

Answer (score 1):

You can get [the length](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_array.asp) of an array in JavaScript using

```
arrayVariable.length
```

Roughly like this:

```
arrayVariable = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(arrayVariable.length);
```

--

In your code you have not created an array.  allCars is an object.

You could get the number of properties in your custom object using [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
var numberOfKeys = Object.keys(allCars).length;
```

If you need this, I have concerns about the underlying data model, though.

--

You could also use a [map data structure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead of an object and then use the size property.

```
let allCars = new Map();
allCars.set('Ford, 'Ka);
allCars.set('GM', 'Sonic');
allCars.set('Audi', 'A4');
console.log(allCars.size);
```

But, I think this is going down a very different route than the code you already shared.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an array to get it's length. The syntax you have creates just an object.

```
class Vehiculo { // represents one vehicle
   name: string;
   model: string;
}

let allCars = Vehiculo[] = [ {name: 'Ford', model: 'KA},  {name: 'Audi', model: 'A4}, ...so on];

console.log(allCars.length); // will print number of cars
```